# Instagram API Geography Subscription Post Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, instagram, instagram-api

Trying to make a POST request with the npm request library in Node.js like so:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();
module.exports = app;

var data = {
client_id: 'XXX',
client_secret: 'XXX',
object: 'geography',
aspect: 'media',
lat: 35.657872,
lng: 139.70232,
radius: 1000,
callback_url: 'http://localhost:1337/auth/instagram/callback'
};

var options = {
uri: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/',
method: 'POST',
form: data
};

request(options, 
 function (err, response, body) {
    console.log(body, "body");
    console.log(err, "error");
});
```

but am receiving this error:

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APISubscriptionError","code":400,
 "error_message":"Invalid URL. The URL may be on a private network."}}
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Any help is greatly appreciated it. Been having trouble setting up a subscription for days now and was told I needed to do it server-side instead of client-side, so this is where I'm at now.

Comment: Do you have the same url in the instagram app settings on instagram.com? `http://localhost:1337/auth/instagram/callback`?

Comment: @Shiva Yes, I do. In the client settings it asks for your website's URL which I have as `http://localhost:1337/` and the Redirect URI which is     `http://localhost:1337/auth/instagram/callback` and what I have placed as my `callback_url` above.

Answer (score 1):

Instagram can't access your `localhost`. 
Taken from their [API documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/):

> When you add a subscription, we will send a GET request to your callback URL to verify the existence of the URL and that want to create the subscription. When we have new data, we'll POST this data to your callback URL. We'll explain more about what this URL needs to do later on this page.

Your problem is that their `GET-request` is failing because they can't access your `localhost`.

You will need to either portforward the port `1337` in your router or use a public IP. You can also try to use [localtunnel.me](http://localtunnel.me/) to setup a tunnel to your localhost

Comment: Thanks for the localtunnel link- this got me further! I've set up localtunnel as my callback_url and I made a get request to the callback url to send the hub.challenge- I'm still getting an error: `"error_message":"Challenge verification failed. Sent \"7a103f5b56244bc2b9adadd8f9996360\", received \"\u003c!DOCTYPE html\u003e\n\u003chtml lang` ....etc.

Comment: Your callback url should ONLY return the parameter that Instagram sends you, in your example, you should ONLY return 7a103f5b562......no HTML or anything, just the parameter as plain text. And I think that you have missunderstood the flow, it's Instagram that will do a GET towards your callback url, not you :) Please have a look here under Create a subscription: https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/

Comment: I thought that was all I was sending- here is a repl.it if you could take a look- http://repl.it/BDqF

Comment: Based on the error message you are recieving, you are sending some html as well. `res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end(req.param("hub.challenge"));`

It's a whole different topic, I think that you should create a new question for this.. :)